# Problema con SQL Server Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, espero se encuentren muy bien.
Tengo un problema algo raro en SQL SERVER.

Cuando creo un Linked Server por primera vez en mi servidor funciona sin ningún problema y permite hacer las consultas, sin embargo, al siguiente día la conexión no funciona, esto ya me ha pasado con dos conexiones ( al mismo servidor que apunto pero con diferente usuario).

Actualmente el servidor al cual estoy apuntando el LS responde al ping y tiene las conexiones remotas activadas ¿a alguien le ha pasado algo similar o me pueden recomendar si puedo revisar algo mas?

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que por defecto SQL Server no permite conexiones remotas en su configuración predeterminada, por lo tanto, asegúrate de que los servicios están levantados y luego habilita las conexiones remotas.
Si aun así no funciona, el error 53 se da cuando quieres conectarte remotamente y no se puede resolver el nombre del servidor, por lo que no puede establecer la conexión. Verifica este tema de resolución del nombre.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose por tu respuesta, verifique y todo lo que tenia estaba correcto, la verdad es que este suceso fue demasiado extraño porque a los dias volvio a funcionar sin que le hiciera nada.